# Xpath nodeValue/textContent unable to see <BR> tag

Tags: php, html, xpath

HTML is as follows:

```
<a href="#">ABC<BR>DEF</a>
```

However, both nodeValue and textContent attributes show `"ABCDEF"` as the value.

Any way to show or parse the `<BR>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this'll help you: [DOMNode::C14N](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php)

It'll return the HTML of the node.

```
<?php
$a = '<a href="#">ABC<BR>DEF</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($a);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes = $finder->query("//a");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    var_dump($node->c14n());
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LjMuE)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I could take this and extract just the contents instead of it showing me the entire HTML?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already solved your problem, but I wanted to add a more direct way of solving it...

```
$a = '<a href="#">ABC<BR>DEF</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($a);
$xp = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xp->query("//a/node()");
$text = '';
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
     $text .= $doc->saveHTML($node);
}
echo $text;
```

Outputs...

```
ABC<br>DEF
```