# Can't store outerHTML of HTML node into variable using xPath + PHP

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm trying to use xPath to get the content of a DOM node INCLUDING the actual node itself. This is similar to what outerHTML would accomplish. Here is the xPath I'm using:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'sp_bypassInliner')]
```

Here is an example of the content I am targeting:

```
<style class="sp_bypassInliner">
 div.class {width:100%}
</style>
```

Here is the return:

```
 div.class {width:100%}
```

Here is what I want returned:

```
<style class="sp_bypassInliner">
 div.class {width:100%}
</style>
```

I'm doing this because we pass the HTML/CSS through a CSS inliner and occasionally I want to exclude HTML from this process. Any help really appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xpath nodeValue/textContent unable to see <BR> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788556/xpath-nodevalue-textcontent-unable-to-see-br-tag)

Comment: https://eval.in/852107

Comment: Well it's different but similar. That gentleman is trying to maintain the HTML tags inside the variable (which I'm not having trouble with) where I'm trying to maintain the wrapping HTML tags.

Comment: Read the accepted answer. It keeps the wrapping HTML tags like you want it to.

Comment: Not working for some reason, I'll run some tests in the morning and get back with a response why. Good info though.

Comment: Upload an excerpt of your code to https://3v4l.org and post it here, maybe we can help you out further.

Comment: Here is a fiddle where you can see the issue: https://3v4l.org/OLRlg

Any advice greatly appreciated. I can't figure out where the discrepancy is coming from.

Comment: Using `$html_fragment = $node->nodeValue;` will take the contents of the node, which is exactly what your getting.

Comment: You all are amazing! Such a simple fix! Here is my latest working fiddle: https://3v4l.org/7Cgko

Does that look appropriate? It's outputting correctly or so it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `$dom->saveHTML($node);` to output the value I was using `$node->nodeValue;` which only brought the contents of the node.

Once I changed to `$dom->saveHTML($node);` it worked great.